# Hits from google bot to urls ending with /customer/customer

Tags: magento2, robots.txt

When we tail -f access.log, we can see a lot of PLP requests coming from googlebot that contains customer/customer/contactus in it. For example requests are coming like below

catalog/product/view/id/689938/category/5075/customer/customer/contactus

But we dont have a url that ends with customer/customer/contactus. The other parts of the URL is valid . The user agent is googlebot and we have verified that it is real googlebot crawler that crawls the site

Comment: Hi, did you check your url rewrite list for this url?

Comment: is your site migrated from an older M1 site? 
do you have some form of contact us extension that could be configured a bit weird?

Comment: did it help you find it or were you just being nice?

Comment: I understand the suggestions are making sense and we got the same opinion from other people also. We are going to implement this to see if it helps. But it seems like this will definitely going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are module-customer routes, but not quite right - and google shouldn't go there

Something is creating a relative link customer/customer/contactus on your pages - and not adding the site base path in front. A module or a badly copy/paste link, likely, or something migrated in the data. See below for suggestions where to look.

But first:

1. use a robots.txt to exclude these paths - even if they were right they don't really need indexing.
   also go to google webmaster tools and use the remove/exclude tools there

this should remove the annoyance while you look for the cause

2. Possible causes

As contactus is not the default contact path (it's `contact` now) you need to figure out what is creating this

First have a look at your full page source and the javacript files it loads to find this link, it might be in a block that gives clues to the culprit

- do you perhaps have a "contact us" popup or overlay which a "contact us" button that google might interpret as a link?
- Have a look at your footer links and the "contact us" configuration
- do you have a "my account" contact tab that is loading in the background even for not logged in customers?
- Have a look at your head content as this might be structured metadata

Once you figure it out, these links need to have noindex,nofollow on them - and unless there's some kind of contact widget they should be absolute, with the store path in them.